# How to get output result from selecting two dropdown menu options in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

If i choose a value from first combobox menu, then the next combobox menu will show only values that inside the first selected combobox value category. and as soon as i click second combobox menu i want my result "Hello" as a output as a text label.

```
The code is as below-

    import tkinter as tk
    
    Classid = ["A", "B", "C"]
    
    subclassid = [["X", "Y", "Z"],["X", "Y", "Z"], ["X", "Y", "Z"]]
    
    root = tk.Tk()
    
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, height = 500, width = 500, bg='white')
    
    canvas.pack()
    
    tkClassid = tk.StringVar(root)
    
    tkClassid.set("Choose")
    
    tksubid = tk.StringVar(root)
    
    tksubid.set('Drug Class')
    
    popupMenu1 = tk.OptionMenu(canvas, tkClassid, Classid)
    
    popupMenu1.pack()
    
    popupMenu2 = tk.OptionMenu(canvas, tksubid, [])
    
    popupMenu2.pack()
    
    def change_dropdown(*args):
    
        print("Chosen Class " + tkClassid.get())
    
            for i in range(len(Classid)):
    
                if tkClassid.get() == Classid[i]:
    
                    popupMenu2["menu"].delete(0, "end")
    
                        for item in subclassid[i]:
    
                            popupMenu2['menu'].add_command(label=item, command=tk_setit(tksubid, item))
    
    tkClassid.trace('w', change_dropdown)
    
    def resultout():
    
        myLabel = Label(root, text=clicked.get()).pack()
    
            if x=='A' and y=='X':
    
                print('Hello')
    
    clicked = StringVar(root)
    
    myButton= Button(root,text='Result', command=resultout).pack()
    
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please fix indentation in your code.

Comment: Hello, i have fixed it.

Comment: @CharitraGour No it is still not proper. your for loops and if statement inside function are not aligned

Comment: I dont know how to fix it but i have edited and re posted it.